# Dynamic array of int in C

Tags: c, vectors

This is my first C program I just wrote in like 30 minutes and I was wondering if you could give me any pointers on ways to improve this. I'm decent at programming (around 5 years experience), but have no experience with C so I imagine I'm not following the proper idioms and/or doing things properly.

**Note:** I didn't make it "generic", because learning templates was beyond the scope of this little adventure.

```c
#include <assert.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/** A dynamically sized array of `int` */
typedef struct {
  size_t capacity;
  size_t length;
  int *data;
} DynamicArray;

/** Appends `value` to the `DynamicArray` */
void dynamic_array_push(DynamicArray *arr, int value) {
  if (arr->length == arr->capacity) {
    int *new_data = malloc(arr->capacity * 2 * sizeof(int));
    memcpy(new_data, arr->data, arr->capacity * sizeof(int));
    free(arr->data);
    arr->data = new_data;
    arr->capacity *= 2;
  }

  arr->data[arr->length] = value;
  arr->length++;
}

/** Cleans up the `DynamicArray`. */
void dynamic_array_cleanup(DynamicArray *arr) { free(arr->data); }

DynamicArray dynamic_array_new(size_t cap) {
  DynamicArray arr = {
      .capacity = cap,
      .length = 0,
      .data = malloc(cap * sizeof(int)),
  };
  return arr;
}

int main() {
  DynamicArray arr = dynamic_array_new(2);

  // Putting in some test values
  for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
    dynamic_array_push(&arr, i);
  }

  // Testing that the data came in correctly
  for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    assert(i == arr.data[i]);
  }

  dynamic_array_cleanup(&arr);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: C doesn't have templates, that's only in C++.

Comment: A quick and dirty way of turning this into kind of generic is to wrap it in a macro that takes a type and the you can easily create `DynamicArray` for any type you like.

Comment: Potential overflow in `cap * sizeof(int)` is a vulnerability.

Comment: @G.Sliepen C does have `generic` which can be used in a C++ template-like fashion.

Comment: I know you're not supposed to have like "thank you" comments but seriously guys thanks for the overwhelming number of extremely helpful comments and answers. I wish I could accept multiple answers! This is honestly the best received post I've had across all of stackexchange and it has really made me happy!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Thank you for the very nice Doxygen comment.
Consider renaming the struct to `DynamicIntArray`,
and then I won't even have to read the comment.
Or perhaps in the use case you're tackling, there is a concept
in the business domain, such as Widget, that can be
represented as an int. Then we'd have a `DynamicWidgetArray`.

## magic number

Some code bases, such as
[BIND9](https://gitlab.isc.org/isc-projects/bind9/-/blob/main/lib/isc/hashmap.c?ref_type=heads#L85),
choose to start (some of) their structs
with a distinct
[magic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)) number.
This is a debugging aid, so library code can choose
to `assert` that an object of the expected type was passed in.

It's completely optional, but you might consider adopting such a practice.
It tends to make debugging with `gdb` a bit easier.

## libc function reimplemented

```
    int *new_data = malloc(arr->capacity * 2 * sizeof(int));
    memcpy(new_data, arr->data, arr->capacity * sizeof(int));
    free(arr->data);
    arr->data = new_data;
```

This is duplicating the functionality of a
[realloc()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/realloc)
call.
For the Author's sake, may as well just reuse a well -tested, -documented function.
For the Gentle Reader's sake, write a single line instead of several, using a familiar
[contract](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract).

## cleanup

In `dynamic_array_cleanup` the free() is very nice.
Consider additionally zeroing out those three fields,
so we don't have a dangling pointer that tempts
some application to try a use-after-free blunder.
Certainly it is accurate that `length` and `capacity`
are zero after the free().

Or write
[0xDeadBeef](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#DEADBEEF)
into them, for the benefit of someone examining memory with `gdb`.

## public API

You have defined a Public API that is broken -- it is not fit for purpose.

Sometimes malloc() returns NULL.
I know, it's sad.
But it's a fact of life.
One which a library author must cope with.
And C doesn't offer error reporting via exceptions.

Each time you make a call, your code must verify that malloc() succeeded.
You should either document that malloc fail will tear down
the calling process, or you should return its status to the caller,
so now it is the caller's problem to decide what to do.

## mulitply by zero

If caller fails to supply new() with a positive number
then Bad Things can happen.
Recycling an old struct after free() can also run afoul of this.
@MatthieuM. observes that

> the growth function does not work with cap == 0, because 0 * 2 == 0. max(cap * 2, 1) will work.

Even `cap * 2 + 1` would suffice.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Zeroing out the fields makes sense. In Rust I would have just taken ownership of the object if I needed to make a cleanup function and that would solve this, so I'm not used to thinking about it haha. With the magic number thing you are saying each struct would have a field at the beginning with the number and then we can essentially polymorphically check the magic number to check the type after receiving a pointer to verify it is of the correct type? That's very interesting... As for the malloc stuff yeah I completely forgot about that...

Comment: `malloc`/copy/`free` isn't just reimplementing `realloc`, it's forcing the worst-case behaviour.  The actual `realloc` function isn't required to suck the way C++ `std::vector` is (unless libraries + compilers are very clever in working around the C++ allocator API), especially for large reallocations.

Comment: I don't feel like adding an answer for just one tiny remark, so I would appreciate if you were to include it in your answer: the growth function does not work with `cap == 0`, because `0 * 2 == 0`. `max(cap * 2, 1)` will work.

Answer (score 14):

#### Use `realloc` - it can be much more efficient than malloc+copy+free

Unlike C++, C's allocator API doesn't totally suck: it has [`realloc`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/realloc.3.html).
(Unfortunately there's no portable `aligned_realloc`, but `malloc`/`realloc` give you memory that's sufficiently for any standard type up to `max_align_t`.  MSVC has [`_aligned_realloc`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/aligned-realloc?view=msvc-170) and `_aligned_calloc`, but I'm not aware of a POSIX or GNU equivalent.)

If there's free memory after the end of the existing allocation, `realloc` can just grow the existing allocation without having to copy anything.  Or if the C library knows how to use a system call like Linux `mremap(MREMAP_MAYMOVE)`  (see the [man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mremap.2.html)), it can move it to a new virtual address without actually copying the physical pages.  (This probably only works if the allocation started at the beginning of a page, but that's what glibc `malloc` does for large allocations.  Actually it keeps the first 16 bytes of the page for bookkeeping data, so unfortunately you get a pointer that's aligned by 16 but misaligned by 32 and wider.  But there isn't unrelated data that `mremap` would unmap from where it's supposed.)  Glibc `realloc` does in fact use `mremap(MREMAP_MAYMOVE)`; I checked with `strace ./a.out` after bumping up the loop count for your test `main` to 2 billion.  Hopefully other `malloc` implementations are similarly smart on platforms they use.

Besides the copying time, the other downside of alloc+copy that is that you need both copies allocated at once.  For a 5 GiB array of int, you'd temporarily have 10 GiB of "dirty" anonymous pages, forcing the OS to find a lot of extra pages.  At best just dropping some potentially-useful disk cache, at worst thrashing swap space as it pages out pages from other processes.

Calling `realloc` is at worst like manually calling `malloc`/`memcpy`/`free`, but can be *much* better, especially for large allocations.  Don't fall into the same trap that C++ `std::vector` is stuck in, of having to always alloc+copy+dealloc when growing.

As a GNU extension, there's a [`reallocarray`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/realloc.3.html) which checks for multiply overflow like `calloc` does (but it doesn't zero the newly-allocated space when growing).  (Available in glibc 2.26.  OpenBSD 5.6, FreeBSD 11.0.)  Portable C should do that manually.

Some implementations, including GCC, [limit the max object size to PTRDIFF_MAX bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9386979/what-is-the-maximum-size-of-an-array-in-c).  If you're going to check manually, that's probably a good limit, unless you really care about bending the implementation limits and having arrays of 2GiB or larger in 32-bit programs for example, right up to `SIZE_MAX`.  (Glibc  `malloc` on 32-bit x86 Linux will allocate arrays larger than 2GiB if you ask it to, for example.  Under a 64-bit kernel you have the full 4GiB of address-space.  Subtracting `int*` first subtracts the raw pointers and then does an arithmetic right shift to scale by `sizeof(int)` ([Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/h8oTMoYGs)), so you could get a negative `ptrdiff_t` instead of e.g. 1 billion, but probably nothing breaks if you don't run any code that relies on that.)

@chux points out that `ptrdiff_t` could be wider than `size_t` in an implementation that wants to allow objects up to SIZE_MAX bytes.  (Such an implementation would then have to effectively widen pointers before subtracting them and dividing or right shifting, perhaps with the help of the carry flag on ISAs that have one.)

**So perhaps `#define DYNAMIC_ARRAY_MAXBYTES (SIZE_MAX/2)`** as a conservative lower bound on implementation-defined limits.  I think if you're going to use `SIZE_MAX/2`, there's no point involving `PTRDIFF_MAX`, since I doubt there are any systems where `ptrdiff_t` is narrower than `size_t` but the max object size is still `PTRDIFF_MAX`.  If you want to be paranoid about that, `#define DYNAMIC_ARRAY_MAXBYTES ((PTRDIFF_MAX <= SIZE_MAX/2) ? PTRDIFF_MAX : SIZE_MAX/2)`.  A C implementation could arbitrarily set a smaller limit on max object sizes if it wanted, but there's no standard macro to expose that.

##### With overflow and allocation-failure checking

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool dynamic_array_push(DynamicArray *arr, int value)
{
  size_t cap = arr->capacity;
  if (cap == arr->length) {
    cap *= 2;     // can't overflow if size_t is at least as wide as ptrdiff_t because it's unsigned.
                  //   But that's not technically guaranteed, so maybe check cap < PTRDIFF_MAX / sizeof(int) / 2 before doubling.  (sizeof(int) == 1 is possible on some DSPs)
    if (cap > PTRDIFF_MAX / sizeof(int)) {
        cap = PTRDIFF_MAX / sizeof(int);   // grow to the max object size for typical C implementations
        if (cap <= arr->length)
            return false;
    }
    int *new_data = realloc(arr->data, cap*sizeof(int));
    if (!new_data) {
        return false;  // original data is still there, but we didn't grow
    }
    arr->data = new_data;
    arr->capacity = cap;
  }

  arr->data[arr->length] = value;
  arr->length++;
  return true;
}
```

I used the same constant twice (`PTRDIFF_MAX / sizeof(int)`) instead of checking against `PTRDIFF_MAX / sizeof(int) / 2` before doubling the capacity.  This hopefully helps compilers only put one 64-bit constant into a register like x86-64 GCC does ([Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/cdzEY8hEx)).

In your exiting API which returns `void`, you could call `abort()` or something on failure, killing the whole process.  That could be a appropriate for a simplistic program, but perhaps better to provide that behaviour via a wrapper like `dynamic_array_push_or_abort` so the documentation of the failure-case behaviour is right there in code using it, easy to search for and start replacing it on a case-by-case basis in a codebase that decides it wants to sometimes do something else.

---

##### A microbenchmark: over 2x faster for huge arrays

For growing the array from size 3 up to 2 billion `int`s (8 GiB) and then reading them back, **using `realloc` is more than twice as fast on my system, with 70x fewer page faults, 9x fewer TLB misses.**  (All the page faults are "soft", not paging to disk.  TLB misses is only counting second-level TLB misses that cause page-walks.)  A good fraction of the extra time is spent in the kernel, zeroing new pages

I timed this vs. the old version on my i7-6700k Skylake with dual-channel DDR4-2666 RAM, running Arch Linux, kernel 6.5, compiled with GCC 13.2.1 `-O3 -fno-plt` (no `-march` options, although it doesn't use any new instructions even if compiled with `-march=native`.  The branching  on size for every push defeats auto-vectorization of the fill pattern.)  My `energy_performance_preference` is `balance_performance` so the CPU only runs 3.9GHz.  [Transparent hugepages](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/next/admin-guide/mm/transhuge.html) are enabled (as with the default), `defrag` is `defer+madvise` (and we're not making `madvise` calls, although my system has 32 GiB RAM, much of it free, so hopefully it is making hugepages.)

```
$ taskset -c 1 perf stat -etask-clock,context-switches,cpu-migrations,page-faults,cycles,instructions,uops_issued.any,dtlb_load_misses.miss_causes_a_walk,dtlb_store_misses.miss_causes_a_walk ./dynarray-slow

 Performance counter stats for './dynarray-slow':

          5,616.15 msec task-clock                       #    0.999 CPUs utilized             
                17      context-switches                 #    3.027 /sec                      
                 0      cpu-migrations                   #    0.000 /sec                      
           779,398      page-faults                      #  138.778 K/sec                     
    21,628,006,730      cycles                           #    3.851 GHz                       
    31,442,121,299      instructions                     #    1.45  insn per cycle            
    29,540,890,921      uops_issued.any                  #    5.260 G/sec                     
         1,710,792      dtlb_load_misses.miss_causes_a_walk #  304.620 K/sec                     
        16,175,526      dtlb_store_misses.miss_causes_a_walk #    2.880 M/sec                     

       5.624499953 seconds time elapsed

       3.514993000 seconds user
       2.093666000 seconds sys
```

```
$ taskset -c 1 perf stat -etask-clock,context-switches,cpu-migrations,page-faults,cycles,instructions,uops_issued.any,dtlb_load_misses.miss_causes_a_walk,dtlb_store_misses.miss_causes_a_walk ./dynarray-fast 

 Performance counter stats for './dynarray-fast':

          2,459.69 msec task-clock                       #    1.000 CPUs utilized             
                 8      context-switches                 #    3.252 /sec                      
                 0      cpu-migrations                   #    0.000 /sec                      
            10,601      page-faults                      #    4.310 K/sec                     
     9,517,533,410      cycles                           #    3.869 GHz                       
    27,308,580,581      instructions                     #    2.87  insn per cycle            
    22,551,679,420      uops_issued.any                  #    9.169 G/sec                     
         1,831,019      dtlb_load_misses.miss_causes_a_walk #  744.412 K/sec                     
           116,378      dtlb_store_misses.miss_causes_a_walk #   47.314 K/sec                     

       2.459971145 seconds time elapsed

       1.574258000 seconds user
       0.881689000 seconds sys
```

The test `main` is the same for both.  The starting point of `3` means we're about half way between growth points when we exit.  (I was just randomly playing with different values for that, this isn't a recommendation, just what I happened to test with.)

```
int main(void)
{
  DynamicArray arr = dynamic_array_new(3);

  // Putting in some test values
  for (int i = 0; i < 2000000000; i++) {
    dynamic_array_push(&arr, i);
  }

  // Testing that the data came in correctly
  for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    assert(i == arr.data[i]);
  }

  dynamic_array_cleanup(&arr);
  return 0;
}
```

The system-calls it makes are:

```
... slow version

brk(NULL)                               = 0x560b599ad000
brk(0x560b599ce000)                     = 0x560b599ce000
brk(0x560b599fe000)                     = 0x560b599fe000
mmap(NULL, 200704, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f3717dd9000
brk(0x560b599ce000)                     = 0x560b599ce000
mmap(NULL, 397312, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f3717b87000
munmap(0x7f3717dd9000, 200704)          = 0
mmap(NULL, 790528, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f3717ac6000
munmap(0x7f3717b87000, 397312)          = 0
...
```

```
... fast version

brk(NULL)                               = 0x5567b45c9000
brk(0x5567b45ea000)                     = 0x5567b45ea000
mmap(NULL, 200704, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fbc9f7d4000       # switch to mmap, will have to copy this time
mremap(0x7fbc9f7d4000, 200704, 397312, MREMAP_MAYMOVE) = 0x7fbc9f582000
mremap(0x7fbc9f582000, 397312, 790528, MREMAP_MAYMOVE) = 0x7fbc9f4c1000
mremap(0x7fbc9f4c1000, 790528, 1576960, MREMAP_MAYMOVE) = 0x7fbc9f340000
mremap(0x7fbc9f340000, 1576960, 3149824, MREMAP_MAYMOVE) = 0x7fbc9f03f000
...
```

Glibc's default `malloc` starts with small allocations from the break                  (`brk`).  This presumably is just extending on `realloc`, vs. alloc+copy leading to some heap-shifting (as @Davislor's answer describes) leaving some allocated + dirty space on the free list, not given back to the OS.  (But which other small allocations could use.)  So that's why we see two `brk` allocations (after the initial `brk(NULL)` to find the break address) from the slow version vs. only one from the `realloc` version before switching over to `mmap` (and copying this one time, at size 1.5MiB I suppose).

Interestingly, `mremap` does keep moving the virtual address, forcing TLB invalidation for the existing part of the array.  With our workload that's append-only until the end, those invalidations don't cause extra TLB misses except in the final read-through after the last growth (when it's so big the start of the array would probably already have been evicted from the TLBs in this case).  And it's a single-threaded process so there's no need for TLB shootdowns (inter-processor interrupts) to other cores.  The downside could be bigger in other cases.

It might be interesting to check `/proc/<PID>/maps` to see if there was free virtual address-space after the mapping.  If not, we're seeing the Heap-Shifting effect that @Davislor's answer talked about, except in reverse.  If there is space, it's a missed optimization not to use it.

Reducing the growth factor to 1.5 for sizes above 512 MiB or something could make sense, especially on platforms like GNU/Linux that are known to have an efficient `realloc` which can use page-table tricks.  Or depending on your use-case, even make growth linear instead of exponential above some threshold like 1 GiB or 1 billion `int`'s.  The amount of work to update N page-table entries is still O(N), but the constant factor is *tiny*.  But more branching for decision making on growth will bloat the code at each use of `push`, if it inlines like you want it to for efficiency in the non-growing case.

---

#### Partial inlining is possible:

```
static inline   // in the .h
bool dynamic_array_push(DynamicArray *arr, int value) {
  if (arr->capacity == arr->length) {
    return dynamic_array_push___growth_needed(arr, value);  // defined in a separate .c file
  }

  arr->data[arr->length] = value;
  arr->length++;
  return true;
}
```

This keeps machine-code size small at each call-site.  It makes every caller a non-leaf function, but that was already true because the growth path called `realloc`.

We could have just split the growth code into a separate function, not duplicating the `arr->data[arr->length] = value;` / `arr->length++;` there and not passing `value` as an arg.  But it's common to `push` values that are temporary at the call-site and not needed after the push.  Passing it as an arg lets the caller avoid needing a [call-preserved register](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9268586/what-are-callee-and-caller-saved-registers/56178078#56178078) for it, instead just computing it in a call-clobbered register since it's dead after the function call.  (I haven't actually looked at an example caller in a loop to see what difference it makes.  This makes the inlined store / increment code conditional on the inlined compare rather than the return value of the `__growth_needed` slowpath, which I expect is probably about equal.  A simplistic caller that just pushes random numbers or loops another array might not be very representative anyway.)

Comment: `cap > PTRDIFF_MAX / sizeof(int)` is the wrong test.   Consider `ptrdif_t` may have 2x the number of bits as `size_t`.  Use `cap > SIZE_MAX / sizeof(int)`.  `prtdiff_t` not needed in this task.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: In theory `ptrdiff_t` could be wider, but it seems unrealistic unless some implementation defines the behaviour of pointer subtraction for pointers to different objects, but limits size of any single object to much smaller than the address-space.  (Or something with non-flat memory models). 
 Perhaps `min(PTRDIFF_MAX, SIZE_MAX)`, since there are implementations (such as GCC) where the implementation-defined max object size is PTRDIFF_MAX bytes.  (This means the compiler can assume pointer subtraction never has signed overflow, including before `sar` for sizeof>1)

Comment: A _wider_ `ptrdiff_t` than `size_t` insures pointer subtraction never has signed overflow, even with objects near size `SIZE_MAX`.

Answer (score 9):

#### Check for Overflow

At present, the algorithm to enlarge the vector does not detect if the capacity wraps around.  It is actually possible, on some architectures, to overflow a `size_t` before getting an out-of-memory error (typically by allocating more than 2GiB on a 32-bit memory model).  Either compare the old size to `SIZE_MAX/2`, or (since it is unsigned, and overflow is guaranteed to truncate) check whether the new size is smaller than the old.

#### Beware of Heap-Shifting

Let’s say you’re working with big data and read the first megabyte into the vector.  So far, so good.  You’ve got plenty of memory in the heap.  You run out of room and need to resize it.  The algorithm checks the heap and finds one free block, past the end of the first one you allocated.  It allocates 2 MB of that copies the entire array to its new location, and frees the original 1 MB.

You have more than 2 MB of data, so you need to resize again. The algorithm checks and finds one free block 1 MB in size, then the allocated block of 2 MB, then a big free block.  It needs 4 MB, which is more than 1 MB, so it allocates 4 MB to the right of the current block, copies the entire array to that, then frees the 2 MB block. You now have a 3 MB free block followed by a 4 MB allocated block.  You need to resize again.  You now need 8 MB, which is too big for your first free block, so you move the array over to the right again and free the previous block to get a 7 MB one. This will keep happening each time, and you will never re-use any of the memory you freed. And copying a large array is expensive!

What happens if you increase the size by only 50% each time, instead of 100%?  After five iterations of this, you will have a free block 8.125 times the size of your original, and you will only need one 7.59 times as large, so you will be able to go back to the beginning of the heap, not keep expanding it further and further to the right.

Of course, the real solution here is to use `realloc()`, which can detect if the current block can be enlarged without moving it.  But that is a problem to be aware of, especially when using C++-style memory management without this feature.

Comment: The way you explained why `realloc` is better made a lot of sense. Seems great to reuse the existing memory without moving if it can be done. Thanks!

Comment: 3 comments: 1) Good explanation. 2) Need to start with allocating `2` to gain traction for 50% increases. 3) "Grow without shifting" may only apply to 'pure' cases of accessing heap. Intervening code (like an innocuous `printf()`) may lead to having to relocate the block anyway.

Comment: Unless you keep large chunks in the free-list (instead of returning them to the OS), that virtual address-space "at the start of the heap" will be unmapped for a while before you use it again.  It's likely that different physical pages will be allocated to map those virtual pages when you map them again, so the reuse doesn't help with L3 cache hits.  (And doesn't help with TLB hits since those TLB entries had to get invalidate on unmap).

Comment: If you're worried about not being able to grow to more than half of virtual address-space with one such array that's the only thing you're allocating, then yeah, a good realloc, e.g. that can use `mremap(MAYMOVE)` or equivalent is important, like I showed in my answer, avoiding double-allocation and the actual memory traffic for copying.  Or like you said by growing an existing allocation if there's nothing after it.  (Or if there's enough space total before+after an allocation, allocate + `memmove`).  But smaller growth factors don't seem great if you typically still copy every time.

Answer (score 8):

A few points (without repeating that `realloc()` would fulfill the need better than a DIY version, or other points in current answers.)

1. `int *new_data = malloc(arr->capacity * 2 * sizeof *new_data);` would be appropriate if/when the array is to become an array of `long` of `double`. Less likely to overlook changing the `sizeof(int)` thereby creating a hard-to-find bug.
2. `...push()` needs to return success or failure, and that return code needs to be checked by the caller.
3. This code mixes passing an entire `struct` (from `dynamic_array_new()`) with passing a *pointer* to the `struct`. I'd prefer to see code following one practice or the other; not mixing both.
4. (nit-picking) Better to use `size_t` (instead of `int`) when coding an array index (as in the loops of `main()`).
5. Read the part of the `realloc()` documentation that says something like "*acts just like `malloc()` if original pointer is NULL.*" In other words, there's no need for an initial allocation in `..._new()`. Just let the first `..._push()` with a NULL pointer perform the initial allocation. Maybe the caller will only create 1 element in the array. You probably already sense that `2` is an arbitrary initial allocation.

---

PS: Revising to use #5, above, would obviate #3. When you want/need an array, simply:

```
    array_t arrN = { 0 };
```

would do the job. All struct members are set to zero (or NULL), and the first `..._push()` handles initialising the length (grows by 1), capacity (set to 1, then doubles on each successive call) and the `data` pointer is initialised then used. Simple...

Comment: Using `void *new_data = ...` instead of `int *new_data = ...` is less maintenance as it supports the "Less likely to overlook changing the sizeof(int)...." concern.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Yes, that's an alternative. I've tended to prefer the datatype "over on the left" and `sizeof var_name` as being easier to see. Is there an advantage (that I'm not seeing) in the version you suggest? Cheers! :-)

Comment: This answer advocates "Less likely to overlook changing the sizeof(int) thereby creating a hard-to-find bug."  By using `void *` on-the-left, we have one less piece of code to update should the type of member `.data` change by similar reasoning.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Thanks :-) I was still in `malloc()` mindset, not `realloc()`, when writing that comment... Thank you `:-)`...

Comment: I should have suggested `void *new_data = realloc(arr->data, sizeof arr->data[0] * arr->capacity * 2);` for a more complete idea.

Answer (score 5):

**Clarifying `size_t` overflow concerns, etc.**

*Test before scaling*, watch out for a 0 capacity, use `realloc()` and size to the referenced object, not type, check for allocation success:

```
// Prevent overflow
if (arr->capacity > SIZE_MAX/2/sizeof arr->data[0]) {
  // Handle overflow with TBD code
}
size_t new_capacity = (arr->capacity > 0) ? arr->capacity * 2 : 1;

void *new_data = realloc(arr->data, new_capacity * sizeof arr->data[0]);
if (new_data == NULL) {
  // Handle out-of-memory with TBD code
}
arr->data = new_data;
arr_capacity = new_capacity;
```